# Adding a search box to an ASP.Net dynamic data list page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Does anyone know how to add a simple search textbox on an ASP.NET Dynamic Data list page? I want to be able to drill down to a specific row immediately, without having to use the dynamic data filters to narrow the scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CodePlex project named [ASP.NET Dynamic Data Filtering](http://www.codeplex.com/DynamicDataFiltering) makes it possible to easily search any information on your site even if you use the Dynamic Data framework from ASP.NET 3.5. Follow [these instructions](http://heyse.us/blog/?p=104) to get a search textbox.

Comment: @pnotus your link took me to a parked godaddy page. Please fix your link, I'd really like to see the page.

Comment: Josh says "You will see an action called UpgradeData source appear in the Action popup, hit it." however I did not see that action and thus was not able to get this to work. Anyone experience that?

Answer (score 2):

The new Dynamic Data 4 preview includes a Data Source called a BusinessLogicDataSource, here are some examples of how you can use it to implement search.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/dynamicdata/dd_AddSearchtoDynamicData.htm

I can't really say how to do it in the current implementation of Dynamic Data, I was searching for this answer as well and stumbled onto both the preview site and this question.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .NETv4 then look at this sample of extending the filtering support in dynamic data [Text Filtering in dynamic data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2010/10/03/text-filtering-with-dynamic-data.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider one of the implementations of search in ASP.NET Dynamic Data Site that works great: [Adding a Multi-Column Search to the Default List page in Dynamic Data](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2011/01/adding-multi-column-search-to-default.html).